# parse mixed jsx and html in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, html-parsing

I would like to parse html generated with tinymce, modified by adding jsx, in react.

Example:

```
import Youtube from "react-youtube"
function Comment() {
  return (
    <div class="comment">
     // I want something that can parse like this
     {parse(`<p>
          <code class="language-javascript">console.log("hi")</code>
          <Youtube videoId="10"/>
          <a href="https://youtu.be/stackoverflow">Youtube</a>
         </p>`)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have come across react-jsx-parser, which doesn't work as expected :(

I have also tried converting html string to jsx string:

```
import parse from "html-react-parser";
import ReactElementToJsxString from "react-element-to-jsx-string";
import { parse as parsehtml } from "node-html-parser";
function modifycomment () {
  const comment = ReactElementToJsxString(parse(`<p>
          <code class="language-javascript">console.log("hi")</code>
          <a href="https://youtu.be/stackoverflow">Youtube</a>
         </p>`));
 const link = parsehtml(comment).querySelector("a");
 return comment.replace(link.toString(), 
 `<Youtube videoId="${link.getAttribute("href"),replace("https://youtu.be/", "")}"${link.toString()}`);;
}
```

Then parse it:

```
import Youtube from "react-youtube";
import JsxParser from "react-jsx-parser";
function Comment () {
   return (
     <div class="comment">
       <JsxParser
        components={{ Youtube }}
        jsx={modifycomment()}
       />
     </div>
   )
}
```

which led to errors in rendering (something like the child to remove is not a child of this Node) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) documentation you just need to pass the video Id. But your code has an extra `<a>` tag.

```
comment.replace(link.toString(), 
 `<Youtube videoId="${link.getAttribute("href"),replace("https://youtu.be/", "")}"${link.toString()}`);
```

and you are not assigning this to anything. I have made changes and did a sample one. Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cdn-f4bgfb?file=/src/App.js)

By the way, I took some sample video